# Accessing a service via a load balancer in an AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have a cluster configured where the services (and their assoicated pods/containers) are all deployed into a private subnet. One of these pods represents the UI for the application and I've defined a load balancer with a public ip to proivde access to the UI. At least that's my intent. When I enter a URL in my browser with the IP of the load balancer, requests are not making it to the UI container. I assume I have something configured incorrectly and some advice would be appreciated. The definition for the UI service looks like this:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata: {name: myui, namespace: gem}
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels: {app: myui}
        spec:
          containers:
            image: myblobstore.azurecr.io/myui:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: myui
            ports:
            - {containerPort: 80}
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata: {name: myapp, namespace: gem}
    spec:
      loadBalancerIP: 40.123.124.125
      ports:
      - {name: '80', port: 80}
      selector: {app: myui}
      type: LoadBalancer
```

I've also defined a rule in my network security group that I had intended to allow traffic from a load balancer to reach the target container:

```
    65001    AzureLoadBalancerInBound   Any  Any  AzureLoadBalancer  Any  Allow
```

Traffic does not make it to the UI container though. What additional configuration do I need to get this to work?

Update: Here are the endpoints for my cluster:

```
$ kubectl get endpoints -n gem
NAME                ENDPOINTS                       AGE
...
myui                10.0.2.22:80                    176m
...
```

And to complete the picture, here's some additional info:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n gem -o wide
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE    IP          NODE                  NOMINATED NODE
...
myui-99c55f8d4-2thzv                 1/1     Running            0          ...

$ kubectl get svc -n gem -o wide
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)             AGE    SELECTOR
...
myui                LoadBalancer   10.1.0.94    40.123.124.125  80:32246/TCP        3h1m   app=myui
...

$ kubectl describe svc/myui -n gem
Name:                     myui
Namespace:                gem
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"myui","namespace":"gem"},"spec":{"loadBalancerIP":"40.123.124,125"...
Selector:                 app=myui
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.1.0.94
IP:                       40.123.124.125
LoadBalancer Ingress:     40.123.124.125
Port:                     80  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 80  32246/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.2.22:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
```

Peter

Comment: can you paste output from `kubectl get endpoints`?

Comment: Done. I've also included the pods and services info for the ui app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if there is an endpoint it should be working... and your service definition looks okay. does it work if you hit the service endpoint (with curl or something) from within the cluster? does it work if you hit the pod directly with curl?

Comment: Are you using advanced networking . In my case i too used advanced networking and the way LB was created was totally weird.THere was no health alerts given by Azure even if i choose any random IP.BB i am using k8s 1.9.3 in azure

Comment: Yes, it works fine within the cluster. In fact, I have a vm on a public subnet and can create an ssh tunnel through to the myui pod, allowing me to connect for example to http://localhost:8080. So I know the UI app is up and running and healthy.

Comment: And yes, I am using advanced networking. I use this so that my pods are created in a private subnet I've configured in my resource group.

Comment: I see that the load balancer itself is created in `MC_blah-blah` resource group that's generated by the `az aks create` operation. I assume that's expected?

Comment: I think the reason the traffic can't get through is because the health probe is failing. The UI has a username/password prompt and when the health probe is attempted the REST call comes back with a `401 Unauthorized`. This is seen by the probe as a failure since it expects a `200` return. We had this same issue when deploying our software to AWS but in that case was able to tweak the health check to accept 401 as a valid response. Is this possible with Azure?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was simply to make sure that the network security group being used has ports 80 and 443 open to allow internet traffic to flow. I had two different security groups and thought my load balancer would use the one I designated as my "public" security group, which did have ports 80 and 443 open. It instead used my other security group, and I had to add the appropriate rules to that group.