# Kubernetes: The service manifest doesn't provide an endpoint to access the application

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

This yaml tries to deploy a simple Arangodb architecture in k8s, I know there are operators for ArangoDB, but it is a simple PoC to understand k8s pieces and iterate this db with other apps.

The problem is this YAML file executes correctly but I don't get any `IP:PORT` to connect, however when I execute that docker image in local it works.

```
# create: kubectl apply -f ./arango.yaml
# delete: kubectl delete -f ./arango.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: nms
  name: arangodb-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: arangodb-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: arangodb-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: arangodb
        image: arangodb/arangodb:3.5.3
        env:
        - name: ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "pass"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8529
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: nms
  name: arangodb-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: arangodb-pod
  ports:
  - targetPort: 8529
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8529
    targetPort: http
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: nms
  name: arango-storage
  labels:
    app: arangodb-pod
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

Description seems clear:

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
arangodb-svc   LoadBalancer   10.0.150.245   51.130.11.13        8529/TCP   14m
```

I am executing `kubectl apply -f arango.yaml` from AKS but I cannot access to any `IP:8529`. Some recommendations?

I would like to simulate these commands:

```
docker run -p 8529:8529 -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -d --name arangodb-instance arangodb/arangodb:3.5.3
docker start arangodb-instance
```

Comment: yeah, install ingress controller first. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

Comment: It was installed

Comment: Can you check if there were no errors while creating the service ? Use `kubectl describe svc arangodb-svc` to verify.

Comment: I created a gist with current state and your command result: https://gist.github.com/gvlpedro/2e8dbe0cdcbea3290617ae17b9411d54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must allow the NodePort 31098 at NSG level from your VNet configuration and attach that NSG rule to AKS cluster.

Also please try and update the service manifest with the changes that you went through with the help in comments.

```
  - targetPort: 8529
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8529
    targetPort: http --< **Its completely wrong field, the manifest wont be parsed.**
```

The above manifest is wrong, for NodePort (*--service-node-port-range=30000-32767*) the manifest should look something like this:

```
  spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: arangodb-pod
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - name: http
      port: 8529
      targetPort: 8529
      # Optional field
      nodePort: 31044
```

You can connect at **public-NODE-IP:NodePort** from outside AKS.

For service type loadbalancer, your manifest should look like:

```
  spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: arangodb-pod
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8529
      targetPort: 8529
```

For LoadBalancer you can connect with **LoadBalancer-External-IP:external-port**

However, in both the above cases NSG whitelist rule should be there. You should whitelist your local machine's IP or the IP of the machine from wherever you are accessing it.

Comment: Thanks!! I got the wrong targetPort property, but I didn´t get why you specify a NodePort, I am not using nodeport, I am using a load balancer, I must replace them? my current approach is in this gist https://gist.github.com/gvlpedro/2e8dbe0cdcbea3290617ae17b9411d54

Comment: ok, i checked the gist it LGTM, I shared the node port because you said you were not getting any IP:PORT to connect. So, I shared both the ways with which you could achieve the same. From the gist you should be accessing on **51.124.59.220:31923**. Also open the same port in your NSG in AKS.

Comment: Seems the key to solve this issue " open the same port in your NSG in AKS." can you say me how or  share with me a documentation link to know how to open this port?

Comment: Anyway other examples with a deployment work perfectly, how it is possible?

Comment: How to open a port in NSG is similar to security groups in AWS. You need to put the source IP ranges/CIDR and destination CIDR and ports for both. What you can do is go to Azure portal. Search from Network Security Groups. Create one and then attach it to your AKS cluster. This is the question about accessing the service via LB in AKS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089927/accessing-a-service-via-a-load-balancer-in-an-aks-cluster
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#network-security-groups

Answer (score 0):

you have to ingress controller or you could also go with loadbalancer type as service assiging a static ip which you prefer. Both will work

Comment: Now I have a 'loadbalancer' as Service type but I have three directions: IP, LoadBalancer Ingress and Endpoint, with two ports: Port 8529/TCP and NodePort 30164/TCP any combination to access is invalid.

Comment: can you share the kubectl get svc output?

Comment: arangodb-svc   LoadBalancer   10.0.77.248   20.50.149.62   8529:31098/TCP   34m.

Comment: ok, i think you might be blocked by your VNET NSG rules and so you will not be able to access this service using public IP. Can you try using your Private IP space for the load balancer so that you get a routable IP in your network.

Comment: maybe, however other sample app like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough is launched correctly.  I will try to find how to build a private IP space...

Comment: could be the TCP/http configuration the problem?

Comment: Try this service spec  `apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: nms
  name: arangodb-svc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: Loadbalancer
  loadBalancerIP: <YOURIP>
  ports:
  - name: http-web
    port: 8529
    targetPort: 8529
  selector:
    app: arangodb-pod`

Comment: it does not work, if I add a static IP is always 'pending' to get external IP otherwise ip:port is not reached. I tried with/without ingress part.

Comment: @OhHiMark thanks for asking, in this moment I am in the same point, I don´t know why a simple application with deployment works but when it is a DB no, it must be a wrong property like 'tcp' or 'http', I don´t know.